# XML to XML (without parent nodes) conversion using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to convert XML file to another XML file using XSLT.

**Input file is:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <listings>
      <listing>
        <listingid>4789231</listingid>
        <listingtype>Land</listingtype>
        <saletype>Sale</saletype>
        <originalsource>CBC Online</originalsource>
        <sourcekey>4789231</sourcekey>
        <cbcofficekey>EDG7023975</cbcofficekey>
        <status>Active</status>
        <name>7218 Bailey Rd</name>
        <address1>7218 Bailey Rd</address1>
        <address2></address2>
        <address3></address3>
        <city>Pearland</city>
        <county>Brazoria</county>
        <stateprovince>TX</stateprovince>
        <postalcode>77584</postalcode>
        <country>US</country>
        <nearestmsa>Yuba City, CA</nearestmsa>
        <baseprice currency="USD">185000.00</baseprice>
        <pricetype>saleprice</pricetype>
        <displayprice>true</displayprice>
        <geolocation>
          <latitude>29.5298</latitude>
          <longitude>-95.3322</longitude>
        </geolocation>
        <preferredunitsofmeasure>IMPERIAL</preferredunitsofmeasure>
        <displayonwww>true</displayonwww>
        <create_ts>2014-06-20T09:09:21Z</create_ts>
        <lastmod_ts>2014-06-26T11:53:14Z</lastmod_ts>
        <overview>
          <propertyoverview>
            <buildingarea>3691.00</buildingarea>
            <yearbuilt>1960</yearbuilt>
            <priceperarea currency="USD">4.99</priceperarea>
          </propertyoverview>
        </overview>
     </listing>
    </listings>
```

**Output I want is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listings>
  <listing>
    <listingid>4789231</listingid>
    <listingtype>Land</listingtype>
    <saletype>Sale</saletype>
    <originalsource>CBC Online</originalsource>
    <sourcekey>4789231</sourcekey>
    <cbcofficekey>EDG7023975</cbcofficekey>
    <status>Active</status>
    <name>7218 Bailey Rd</name>
    <address1>7218 Bailey Rd</address1>
    <address2></address2>
    <address3></address3>
    <city>Pearland</city>
    <county>Brazoria</county>
    <stateprovince>TX</stateprovince>
    <postalcode>77584</postalcode>
    <country>US</country>
    <nearestmsa>Yuba City, CA</nearestmsa>
    <baseprice currency="USD">185000.00</baseprice>
    <pricetype>saleprice</pricetype>
    <displayprice>true</displayprice>
    <geolocation_latitude>29.5298</geolocation_latitude>
    <geolocation_longitude>-95.3322</geolocation_<longitude>
    <preferredunitsofmeasure>IMPERIAL</preferredunitsofmeasure>
    <displayonwww>true</displayonwww>
    <create_ts>2014-06-20T09:09:21Z</create_ts>
    <lastmod_ts>2014-06-26T11:53:14Z</lastmod_ts>
    <overview_propertyoverview_buildingarea>3691.00</overview_propertyoverview_buildingarea>
    <overview_propertyoverview_yearbuilt>1960</overview_propertyoverview_yearbuilt>
    <overview_propertyoverview_priceperarea>4.99</overview_propertyoverview_priceperarea>      
 </listing>
</listings>
```

If parent has child nodes then output xml should contain node with parent plus child node name. Here I want parent nodes should be concatenated with child node name according to their hierarchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the identity template and these additional templates.

```
<xsl:template match="listing//*[*]">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="listing//*[not(*)]">
  <xsl:variable name="newName">
    <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*[count(ancestor::*) &gt; 1]">
      <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
      <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">_</xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:element name="{$newName}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
  </xsl:element>    
</xsl:template>
```

The expression `ancestor-or-self::*[count(ancestor::*) &gt; 1]`, as seen from the context of a `<yearbuilt>` node:

```
<listings>                            <!-- not selected -->
  <listing>                           <!-- not selected -->
    <overview>                        <!-- selected     -->
      <propertyoverview>              <!-- selected     -->
        <yearbuilt>1960</yearbuilt>   <!-- selected     -->
```

Comment: Hi Tomalak.. thanks for your answer. I tried with your XSL file. But it's not generating XML elements. It generates only value in file not a with node. I am transforming using c sharp.

Comment: I tried Tomalak's solution and it works. You should add an identity template, though, per his suggestion.

Comment: Joel. I found the issue because of which i am not getting the desired output. Its because of this line-
<listings xmlns="http://www.cbcworldwide.com/ns/listings"
If i remove the attribute xmlns then its working fine. Plus listings/listing tag is not coming in final output. I am trying for that. Please help as i am new to XSLT.

Comment: Add the namespace declaration to your `<xsl:stylesheet>` and you should be all-right.

Comment: @Tomalak Tried.. But no luck.

Comment: also this line is not added in output file.. because which i guess browser didn't recognize the XML ...

Comment: See here: http://www.xmlplayground.com/8PQsoN - The namespace must be added twice: Once as default namespace (this determines which namespace the output will be in) and once with a prefix (this is necessary so the XPath in the XSLT can use it - see the modified `match` expressions).

Comment: Advice for next time: XML namespaces may look like meaningless attributes. They are not. They are an extremely important bit of information, you can never silently remove them when you ask questions here. If you do, people will be confused, answers will not work and, yeah... everyone's time will be wasted. ;)

Comment: Thanks Tomalak... Next time i will keep your advice in mind.... :) 
One more thing, i am trying to append counter for that each element so that while selecting i will get unique node. I tried by appending with counter variable. But i failed. every time its adding same no. can u pls suggest any solution????

Comment: That's material for a new question. You can read about & experiment with `<xsl:number>`, this will do counting/numbering for you. For example here: http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/11/06/tr.html, but there are many other pages that explain it.